# How do I say no to "the new Skype preview"?

Tags: windows-10, skype

After being upgraded to Windows 10 Anniversary Edition, I was greeted with this screen when I started Skype[image]

As you can see, there is no "No, thanks" button. Clicking on the cross simply minimizes the window, the menus contain nothing useful (apart from Skype->close, which again minimizes the window), and none of the words on the screen seem clickable apart from the big blue button. How does one continue to use Skype without joining the preview? This window replaces the Skype main window, so it is impossible to use Skype normally while it is open. This  whole situation seems a bit Kafkaesque.

Comment: "Classic Skype" is the desktop application.  What you have there is the UWP version of Skype.  If yu want to use the UWP version of Skype you have to use the preview version, there isn't another version, that isn't in a preview stage.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use "Skype for Windows" (the desktop, non-Store app) even after installing the preview. I never got a screen like that - possibly because I already have the preview installed - but I'm on the last Windows Insider Fast build and just launched Skype (desktop version) and it works fine still. You can *probably* even just delete the preview app after installing it without the nag screen coming back, although no guarantees.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use version web if you wanna make it easy, otherwise another skype user asked it, you can see his question and answer in Skype forum [here](https://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-archive/I-don-t-want-the-latest-update/td-p/3800077).

> Clear your internet cache, stop the skype update service (Click right button on my computer > manage)
>
> Add 127.0.0.1  download.skype.com to your hosts file. This should stop skype from doing that.